# Digits after the decimal point are gone after sorting

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a bubble sort algorithm.
However, when I enter some floating point numbers (`double` type), digits after the decimal point are gone.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void bubbleSort(double numbers[], int SIZE);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const int SIZE = 10;
    double numbers[SIZE];

    // read in SIZE numbers
    printf("Please enter %d numbers: ", SIZE);
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        scanf("%lf", &numbers[i]);
    }

    // print array contents
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("%lf ", numbers[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    bubbleSort(numbers, SIZE);
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("%.2f ", numbers[i]);
    }
}

void bubbleSort(double numbers[], int SIZE)
{
    int swap = 0;
    bool isSorted = false;
    int lastUnsorted = SIZE - 1;
    while (!isSorted)
    {
        isSorted = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < lastUnsorted; i++) {
            if (numbers[i]> numbers[i + 1])
            {
                swap = numbers[i];
                numbers[i] = numbers[i + 1];
                numbers[i + 1] = swap;
                isSorted = false;
            }
        }
        lastUnsorted--;
    }
}
```

Below is an example.

```
Please enter 10 numbers: 5.4 4.1 0.0 -1.5 2.7 9.8 -2.2 3.3 4.1 8.1
-2.200000 -1.000000 0.000000 2.000000 3.300000 4.000000 4.100000 5.000000 8.100000 9.000000
--------------------------------
Process exited after 17.78 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

---

As you see, some numbers are displayed as inputted. but others are seen differently. e.g) I entered `9.8` but it is seen as `9.000000`.

Can you tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 5):

The type of your `swap` variable (currently `int`) needs to match the type of the values you are swapping (currently `double`)

So anytime you swap two values, the one that is assigned to `swap` is currently being downcast to type `int`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the way you swap. You are casting a double to an int (your swap variable), which can result in undefined behaviour.

The C Standard, 6.3.1.4, paragraph 1 says:

> When a finite value of real floating type is converted to an integer type other than _Bool, the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the value is truncated toward zero). If the value of the integral part cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is undefined.

So in your input case the result is loss of precision.

Just change the type of the swap variable to match the type of the numbers you sort.

Comment: Thank you all for advice. now I get what did incorrectly!